# Is my handlers design fine?

Tags: java, netty

So I've been writing a server with netty and I haven't written anything else with it so Im wondering if my approach to pipeline is correct.


I have 2 default handlers in server and client, ObjectEncoder and Decoder and I thought about making a new handler for each feature I add to my server for example I have a UserAuthenticationHandler, UserActionHandler and each of them handles different packets and passes them to corresponding classes.


So this is one of approach I got in my mind the other one is one handler for every feature which means I'll have to write a big switch to handle all of them.

Is it okay to use first approach or should I stay with the second one?

## Example of first approach

```
public class UserAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractPacketHandler {
    private User user;

public UserAuthenticationHandler(User user, DatabaseConnection databaseConnection) {
    this.user = user;
    new UserAuthenticator(databaseConnection);
}

@Override
protected void handlePacket(Packet packet) {

    switch (packet.packetType){
        case "START_LOGIN":
            UserAuthenticator.startLoginProcess(packet, user);
    }
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelActive(ctx);
}

public User getUser(){
    return user;
}
```

}

## Second approach

Just imagine the first one but with 50+ switch cases and big as hell constructor for every class.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: @ivonet I added my current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would advise to have different handlers if it makes sense as these will act on different messages. That said from what you explained this not really seems like it be the case. I think in your case you should just have the decoder / encoder and then one handler which dispatch to the correct "business logic" interface of your app.